# glload and LNK errors in VC++ EE 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, linker, glload

I'm trying to use glload from the Unofficial OpenGL SDK but I get LNK errors:

```
1>  LINK : C:\Users\T\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testi\Debug\testi.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>glloadD.lib(gll_gl_ext.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4 referenced in function _WinGetProcAddress
1>glloadD.lib(wgll_ext.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4 
1>C:\Users\T\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testi\Debug\testi.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

```
#include <glload/gl_all.h>
#include <glload/gll.hpp>

void main()
{
    glload::LoadFunctions();
}
```

Linker/Additional Dependencies: glloadD.lib
Where is the problem ?

**Edit 1:**

First I used Premake to generate build files for vs2010. Then I built all libraries. In my project I set Additional Include Directories, Additional Library Directories and Additional Dependencies for those libraries. I want to run an example from this page: [link](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glimg.html) but I forgot to create OpenGL context before loading opengl functions. I don't need a window in this project so I just call glutInit, but I get an unhandled exception at 0x5bfed398 (msvcr100d.dll)

```
#include <glload/gl_all.h>
#include <glload/gll.hpp>
#include <freeglut/freeglut.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glload::LoadFunctions();
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Calling glutCreateWindow before glload::LoadFunctions seems to be necessary. Following code works:

```
#include <glload/gl_all.h>
#include <glload/gll.hpp>
#include <freeglut/freeglut.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("");
    glload::LoadFunctions();
}
```

Comment: We're going to need something more than that. Like a full accounting of how you built everything, what libraries you're linking to, etc. Also, even if it were to compile and link, your source code wouldn't do anything, because you can't load OpenGL functions until you have created an OpenGL context.

Comment: BTW, when you discover the answer to your own question, it is generally customary to write it as an actual *answer* to the question, not as an addendum to the question. It's OK to answer your own question. Stack Overflow isn't a forum; it's a Q&A site, so we like questions to have answers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a working context before initializing GlLoad. I've had this problem every time i've started an OpenGL project with GLSDK.